# About NHibernate's ISession

Tags: nhibernate, isession

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473019/how-to-properly-use-a-nhibernate-isession-object-session-is-closed-errors) question, the user asks the better way to close sessions because he was having some errors.

The most voted answer is Ayende's answer that says:

> You should always use session.Dispose(); The other are for very strange occurances

Should I really always call `session.Dispose()`? Isn't enough to call `session.Close()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Session Dispose() does a couple more things than just Close()ing](http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Impl/SessionImpl.cs?revision=5225&view=markup#l1666), so yes, always use Dispose()

Answer (score 5):

Rule of thumb in .net is "if class is `IDisposable` always call `Dispose`", but better use `using`