# Windsor: how to dispose objects created using interface-based typed factory

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I started using Windsor and found this very, very cool feature: typed factories. I learned that whenever I use the factory to get an instance, I also have to ask it to destroy the instance when I don't need it. I was wondering how this applies to an extremely common operation such as opening a file on disk. The model:

```
interface IDisk
  IFile OpenFile(string path)
interface IFileFactory
  IFile Create(string path)
  void Destroy(IFile openFile)
interface IFile // empty, it's not important what it does

class Disk : IDisk
  ctor(IFileFactory fileFactory)
  IFile OpenFile(string path)
     return fileFactory.Create(path)
```

User code:

```
disk = container.Resolve<IDisk>() // disk is root so this is not SL
file = disk.OpenFile("foo.bar");
// do something with file
```

Now comes the time to get rid of the file. The average .NET user would call `file.Dispose()`. But this time things are different:

- the file is an interface which does not inherit `IDisposable` (if it did then it would be a leaky abstraction); however the `File` class implements `IDisposable`
- the file was created by a factory which owns it

So here's another way: instead of `Dispose`, the `IFile` interface has an extra method `Close` which is supposed to release the file instance from the factory, which in turn call `Dispose` on the `File` instance. For this to work the `File` class must either be aware of the file factory (which I don't like) or of its `Destroy` method:

```
class File : IFile
  ctor(Action<IFile> destroyCallback)
```

I don't like this either... I could avoid all this trouble if I change the model such that the file does not close itself, but the disk closes the file:

```
//file.Close() // not supported, by design
disk.Close(file)
```

This is easier for me who wrote the `Disk` and `File` class, but I worry that my users will not appreciate this "new pattern".

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let me address that in order:

> The average .NET user would call file.Dispose().

Calling `file.Dispose()` is wrong, regardless of whether you're using a container or not. The rule in .NET is that you are not supposed to destroy what you didn't create.

That applies to `.Dispose()` as well as `ctor(Action<IFile> destroyCallback)`

So who owns the *file*? as far as your code is concerned, the factory does. Therefore it's factory's responsibility to clean up after the file.

If you keep the factory as an implementation detail of the `Disk` (as you most likely should) then it's the `Disk` who is your surface area API for opening **and closing** the *file* therefore it needs to have a `Close(IFile file)` method which as implementation detail passes that down to the factory.

Therefore the usage of the file would look like the following:

```
var myfile = disk.OpenFile(@"c:\myfile.txt);
try
{
   DoSomethingWithTheFile(myFile);
}
finally
{
   disk.Close(myFile);
}
```

[EDIT: based on the comment]

Well if you expect, and want your users to have some `IDisposable` object, then give them one (I would rather advise against this, but it's not my call)

The `OpenFile` method would then return object that looks like:

```
public class FileScope:IDisposable
{
   private Action<IFile> close;

   public FileScope(IFile file, Action<IFile> close)
   {
      File = file;
      this.close = close;
   }


   public IFile File {get; private set;}

   public void Dispose()
   {
      close(file);
   }
}
```

The close delegate would be callback to `disk.Close`, as in

```
public FileScope OpenFile(string path)
{
   return new FileScope(fileFactory.Create(path),Close);
}
```

Comment: I totally agree with this. What I meant by "The average .NET user would call file.Dispose()" is that the standard way to do this in .NET is e.g. `using (var file = File.OpenRead("file")) { ... }` in which case the caller owns the file instance and it's responsible for its destruction. My concern was that people are so used to cleaning up after themselves that they often forget the ownership rule. Like "ok i'm done with this file, now I just have to call Dispose on it... but wait, there's no Dispose!" Anyway, they'll have to deal with this because this one's a keeper, sir!

Comment: About your edit: I can't figure out how the file instance can be set inside the `FileScope`. The setter is private and it's not injected in the ctor either...

Comment: It should be passed into the .ctor from `Disk` who creates it. Let me fix that.

Comment: Thank you! I will try `disk.Close(file)` and see how this works. The `FileScope` is also a good idea and it is easy to switch to it if needed later.

Comment: I dispute your statement "The rule in .NET is that you are not supposed to destroy what you didn't create.". I see that pattern used all the time. For example, the endorsed pattern of nHibernate session management is a code block like `using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession()) { ... }`. See [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1473162/25216)